# why WSO2 ID token returns 'groups' attributes as a comma seperated role string instead of list of role

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I've two WSO2 IS 5.7.0 environments. The id tokens returned by https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token have slight difference. the first environment: the 'groups' attribute has values like the following:

```
"groups": [
    "FOTA_WEB_View_User",
    "FOTA_Engineer",
    "FOTA_Manager",
    "FOTA_WEB_Admin",
    "Internal/everyone",
    "_login",
    "FOTA_APP"
  ]
```

but in the second environment, the 'groups' attribute has values like the following：

```
"groups": "BDA-AA-Flameout-Download,BDA-Diag-TempSensor-Download,BDA_Admin,BDA-AA-Superknock-Download,Internal/everyone,_login,BDA-AA-Flameout-View,BDA-AA-Superknock-View"
```

Actually, **the first is expected.**

The configration seems the same, i.e. add a new service provider, and then add 
Requested Claims. see below pictures.
[image]

Comment: note I've configured mysql as my user store.

Comment: Have you done any changes to the MultiAttributeSeparator in the user store configuration?

Comment: I don't understand. where's it?

Comment: The first environment uses default embedde ldap as user store. The second uses mysql. Is that the difference? Unfortunately, our app framework(istio service mesh) only accepts list of roles.

Comment: Could you please check the value of MultiAttributeSeparator property under JDBCUserStoreManager in the user-mgt.xml. This file is located in <IS-HOME>/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml. Default value is a ",".

Comment: it's not set actually.

Comment: actually in my 2nd environment, it returns 'groups' as single string. But in my 1st environment, it returns 'groups' as array of strings. Do you know why?

Comment: it's solved by adding <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property> in <IS-HOME>/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml

Answer (score 1):

A possible way to happen this is not configuring the **MultiAttributeSeparator** property in **user-mgt.xml** (/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml) file. This property is available in all UserStoreManager classes. In this case we need to set the value for the **MultiAttributeSeparator** property to comma (`,`) in the **JDBCUserStoreManager** properties since the user store is a JDBC database (MYSQL).